# kendo(Asp.Net MVC) grid data result depending on other controls input

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I Have a Kendo Grid (UI for Asp.Net MVC) on my page. It gets results from database using an action method of a controller which is bound at grid initialization.And the page has some other controls(one button,some text box).I hope click the button and get the text box value as parameters to grid and do filter in action method of controller,Please suggest.

Comment: if you post how ur view/javascript/controller look like it will be easier for us to help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will pay attention next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grid should have a read option in the DataSource, to wich you can add a "Data" option, where you pass some parameters to your controller:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName").Data("getUserInput"))
```

Then, you must define your "getUserInput" function, using jquery, sth like this:

```
function getUserInput() {
 return {
     parameterName: $("#textbox").val(),
}
```

To get those parameters, just add them to your "ActionName" header in your controller
Make sure that the parameterName is the same in your function as in your controller!!!! Order does not matter, but the name MUST be the same, else you won't get the values.

Try that, see how far you get. Feel free to ask for anything

Comment: Thanks，According to your suggestion , I have resolved